# ASP.NET / MVC 1.0 Components and Ajax controls - Grid - Calendar - Search?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, components

Hello I'm rather new to developing with MVC and I'm looking to find as many Ajax controls that integrate seamlessly into my new MVC 1.0 ASP.Net application. Specifically, tree controls, searching, outlook calendaresque, and inline updating.

Answer (score 3):

You should see jQuery plugins.

Some of them are commented [here](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/01/top-10-jquery-plugins-for-form-usability/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe all the controls should work fine under MVC, it's still ASP.NET at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik do some excellent controls at http://www.telerik.com. Their support is EXCELLENT.